# Can we upload Android's .apk file to MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, apk

I was wondering if it's possible to upload the .apk file to MySQL database and make em downloadable.

Even if it's possible, would it be a good choice to primarily use the database to handle all the uploaded files? Or a web server is a must needed for this kind of purpose?

Comment: It would probably be unwise to use a MySQL database to store blobs with sizes in the megabytes, at least without any special configuration. Anyway, you'd need a client to somehow fetch the APK to download/install it, and HTTP clients are already ubiquitous.

Comment: For low-to-mid range traffic, files on the web hosting server might work better.  For high traffic or if you are using cloud server(s), a cloud storage bucket like Amazon S3.